# Find the owner of a directory or file, but only return that and nothing else

Tags: shell-script, ls

I am looking for a command that will return the owner of a directory and only that--such as a regex parsing the `ls -lat` command or something similar? I want to use the result in another script.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

[`stat`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stat-invocation.html)  from [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) can do this:

```
stat -c '%U' /path/of/file/or/directory
```

Unfortunately, there are a number of versions of `stat`, and there's not a lot of consistency in their syntax.  For example, on FreeBSD, it would be

```
stat -f '%Su' /path/of/file/or/directory
```

If portability is a concern, you're probably better off using [Gilles's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7730/find-the-owner-of-a-directory-or-file-but-only-return-that-and-nothing-else/7733#7733) of combining `ls` and `awk`.  It has to start two processes instead of one, but it has the advantage of using only POSIX-standard functionality:

```
ls -ld /path/of/file/or/directory | awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: stat -c %U /path, if brevity is a bonus.

Comment: That assumes GNU stat, which is not the case on older Linux systems (even on newer systems I'd be wary, there might be a different `stat` (a site-wide standard) in `/usr/local/bin` or somewhere in the user's home), and is rarely available on other unices.

Comment: `stat -c %U` has the advantage of also working with [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#stat), if the `stat` command is compiled in.

Comment: Nice, the last example (ls) works both on Unix/OSX and Linux

Comment: Note that ls will print the uid if there's no local user matching the owner (i.e., on a network share), but `stat -c '%U' DIR` will print `UNKNOWN`, which is less helpful or more appropriate, depending on how you look at it.

Comment: Thanks for portable solution and clarifying `stat` :-).

Answer (score 25):

[Parsing the output of `ls` is rarely a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but obtaining the first few fields is an exception, it actually works on all “traditional” unices (it doesn't work on platforms such as some Windows implementations that allow spaces in user names).

```
ls -ld /path/to/directory | awk 'NR==1 {print $3}'
```

Another option is to use a `stat` command, but the problem with `stat` from the shell is that there are multiple commands with different syntax, so `stat` in a shell script is unportable (even across Linux installations).

Note that testing whether a given user is the owner is a different proposition.

```
if [ -n "$(find . -user "$username" -print -prune -o -prune)" ]; then
  echo "The current directory is owned by $username."
fi
if [ -n "$(find . -user "$(id -u)" -print -prune -o -prune)" ]; then
  echo "The current directory is owned by the current user."
fi
```

Comment: There are some caveats with the `ls | awk` approach too unfortunately, as [I've noted here](http://superuser.com/questions/581989/bash-find-directory-group-owner#comment1016101_717007). I haven't yet come up with a solution for the, "target file/dir is a symlink with a different name," issue I mentioned in my recent comment.

Comment: Instead of `find . -user "$username" -print -prune -o -prune` you could just do `find . -maxdepth 0 -user "$username"`

Comment: @Gilles Is there any reason you use `awk 'NR==1 {print $3}'` instead of just `awk '{print $3}'`? I'm not sure why the `NR==1` is necessary here.

Comment: @HaroldFischer Only in an edge case where the path contains a newline. It's rarely necessary, but never harmful.

Comment: @Gilles Very good to know!! Just curious, are you aware of an implementation of `ls` where a newline in a path causes the line to be split in two (which I believe is the edge case you are trying to cover)? On GNU `ls` (newish version), BusyBox `ls` and FreeBSD `ls` a newline is returned as `$'\n'`, `?` and `?`, respectively.

Comment: @HaroldFischer IIRC that's a recent change. GNU ls defaulted to `?` until fairly recently and older versions treated newlines as printable.

Answer (score 14):

One can also do this with GNU `find`:

```
find "$directoryname" -maxdepth 0 -printf '%u\n'
```

This isn't portable outside of the GNU system, but I'd be surprised to find a Linux distribution where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

In pure bash you can convert the output of `ls` to an array and index into it.

```
# (lrwxr-xr-x, 1, myuser, staff, 36, Oct, 21, 16:36, /path/to/file)    
file_meta=($(ls -ld /path/to/file))
file_owner="${file_meta[2]}" # myuser
```

It's not as elegant as using `stat`, `find`, or `awk`, but could work in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -ld /path/to/file/or/directory | cut -d' ' -f3
```